# what is the equivalent of ByteBuffer.wrap in dart?

Tags: dart, byte, uint8list

I have the following snippet of code to be converted to dart.

**JAVA CODE**

```
static final byte[] MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST = new byte[]{(int) 1, (int) 2, (int) 3, (int) 4};
ByteBuffer bf =   ByteBuffer.wrap(MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST);
int certLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(macIdBytes).getInt();
```

**Dart**

Using Uint8List in Dart instead of byte[] and how to do ByteBuffer.wrap & use .getInt() on Uint8List ?

```
final Uint8List MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST = Uint8List.fromList([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: Perhaps [`Uint8List.buffer.asByteData().getInt32()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getInt32.html) (or [`.getUint32()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getUint32.html))?

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the response, 
I tried executing with Uint8List.buffer.asByteData().getInt32() but the out put of java & dart are different.

Comment: I tried this and its giving me a proper result.
```MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST.buffer.asByteData().getInt32(0)```

Answer (score 2):

As per the Documentation :
https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html

Tried something like this and getting the same output in Java & Dart.

```
MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST.buffer.asByteData().getInt32(0)
```

Comment: Or: `MESSAGE_M1_REQUEST.buffer.asInt32List()[0]`.